# pagination styling in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have a pagination code Like below.

I want to apply num_active class for span which points to the page which is active and
num for inactive.

```
        <div class="pagination"> 
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
          <span class="prev"></span>
          <span class="num" id="1">1</span> 
          <span class="num_active" id="2">2</span> 
          <span class="num" id="3">3</span> 
          <span class="num" id="4">4</span> 
          <span class="num" id="5">5</span> 
          <span class="num" id="6">6</span> 
          <span class="next"></span>
         </div>
```

I Tried the below code but in vain.

```
      $('.pagination span').click(function(){
        $('.pagination span').addClass('num');

        this.addClass('num_active');    
      });
```

What I Tried is to add num class for all the span with in pagination div and num_active for the span which i clicked.

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".pagination span").click(function() {
  // Reset all span to `num` class
  $(".pagination span").removeClass("num_active").addClass("num"); 
  // Add `num_active` only to this.
  $(this).addClass("num_active"); 
});
```

Comment: yes but i want it to be applied for span with in pagination div the first and last with prev and next class applied to it.

Comment: When the page is inactive num will be applied to that.If actine num_active is applied to span.So before applying num_active to a particular page which i clicked i shld apply num class to span which is inactive

Comment: How you would specifically tell to apply this for span within div with pagination class applied to it

Comment: I want the num class applied to span with in div which has pagination class applied to it

Comment: With the `".pagination"` selector. I made the changes.

Comment: I love you Aesthete Its Working